# Flickering canvas when loading multiple graphs with springy.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, springy.js

When rendering a new graph to the canvas with [springy.js](http://getspringy.com/), on mouseover I am experiencing a flickering between the new graph and the old graph that was previously loaded.

To reproduce run the snippet below and click the change graph button and then mouseover the canvas.

```js
function drawGraph(data) {

  var graph = new Springy.Graph();
  graph.loadJSON(data);

  $('#graph-canvas').springy({
    graph: graph
  });

}

var graphs = [{
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'e', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['b', 'd', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['c', 'b', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['d', 'a', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['c', 'a', {color: '#0000ff'}]
  ]
}, {
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'e', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['b', 'a', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['c', 'e', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['d', 'a', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['e', 'b', {color: '#00ff00'}]
  ]
}, {
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'd', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['b', 'e', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['c', 'f', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['d', 'f', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['e', 'd', {color: '#ff0000'}]
  ]
}]

drawGraph(graphs[2]);

$('#draw-graph').click(function() {
  drawGraph(graphs[Math.floor(Math.random() * graphs.length)])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/springy/2.7.1/springyui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/springy/2.7.1/springy.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph-canvas" width=600 height=600>

</canvas>

<button id="draw-graph">
  change graph
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue you are seeing don't create a new `graph`, `layout` and `renderer` for each graph, just clear the graph then load the new data.

```js
var renderer;

function drawGraph(data) {

  if (renderer) {
      renderer.graph.edges.slice().map(function(edge) {
          renderer.graph.removeEdge(edge);
      });
      renderer.graph.nodes.slice().map(function(node) {
          renderer.graph.removeNode(node);
      });
      renderer.graph.loadJSON(data);  
  } else {
      var graph = new Springy.Graph();
      graph.loadJSON(data);
      renderer = $('#graph-canvas').springy({
         graph: graph
      });
  }
}

var graphs = [{
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'e', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['b', 'd', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['c', 'b', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['d', 'a', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['c', 'a', {color: '#0000ff'}]
  ]
}, {
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'e', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['b', 'a', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['c', 'e', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['d', 'a', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['e', 'b', {color: '#00ff00'}]
  ]
}, {
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'd', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['b', 'e', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['c', 'f', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['d', 'f', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['e', 'd', {color: '#ff0000'}]
  ]
}]

drawGraph(graphs[2]);

$('#draw-graph').click(function() {
  drawGraph(graphs[Math.floor(Math.random() * graphs.length)])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/springy/2.7.1/springyui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/springy/2.7.1/springy.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph-canvas" width=600 height=600>

</canvas>

<button id="draw-graph">
  change graph
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Two solutions

**The right way**

I wrote an answer but now as I am about to submit it I realise that it is a terrible solution.

The answer should be.. If you want to change the graph you need to reload the page as that seems to be the design intent of the Springy.js author.

Or Jquery may have a way?

Below is the original answer if reloading the page is impractical

**The ugly way**

Having had a quick look at the code and assuming the flicker you mention is it switching between different graphs.

The reason for this is instantly obvious for those with a little canvas experience.  You have two or more renders running, each of which is requesting a render frame and the browser will present what it thinks is the correct frame. The result is flicking between the two renders.

I dont use JQuery so the solution may well lay in JQuery if it has a way to dereference a plugin and all associated.

Then solution, I thought, would be to just stop the renderer. So I had a quick look at the prototype of `Springy` (put it to the console with `console.log(graph)`) but found nothing there that could do this via a simple call.

You can't just dereference the graph by overwriting or deleting as it will maintain its reference because it is constantly calling `requestAnimationFrame()`

So looking through the source code it becomes evident that springy.js has not provided a generic reset or stop so that it can be dereferenced and started again. (something the author should consider providing)

So I then thought the way to stop it is to access the `Springy.eventListeners` array. Iterate that array and anything that has the method `stop` just call it. When done you can then safely dereference Springy and create a new one. No luck :(

**Forced error.**

Notes regarding example code below
NOTE 1

I wrote the above then tried the code and calling stop had no effect so more drastic action was required. The code below still includes the nice attempt (plus the debugging stuff) but after the stop call I had to force it to stop by replacing a required function with a cow, sorry I mean string. This made it stop

NOTE 2

I have used a time out to give Springy time to crash, but it is possible that the render does not use the method `drawNode` and thus not crash.

**The Demo that solved the flicker.**

```js
var graph;  // needs to be global or in scope
function drawGraph(data) {
  if(graph !== undefined){  // it already exists so must be stopped and dereferenced.
     // safely find eventListeners and iterate
     if(graph.eventListeners !== undefined && typeof graph.eventListeners.forEach === "function"){ 
        graph.eventListeners.forEach(function(listener){
             console.log(listener); // debug info
             if(typeof listener.stop === "function"){                     
                 listener.stop();
                 // See above SO answer NOTE 1
                 // OK this did not stop it. So time to poke it in the eye
                 // forcing it to error by replacing a function 
                 if(typeof listener.drawNode === "function"){                     
                     listener.drawNode = "have a cow"; 
                 }

             }
        })
        

        // I am not sure if this needs the next frame or not so am playing it safe
        // by giving it a little time 1/4 second to settle
        setTimeout(function(){
            // I am not a JQuery user so not sure if this will upset it
            // remove it from the DOM
           var canvas = document.getElementById("graph-canvas");
           if(canvas !== null){
               canvas.springy = undefined;
           }
           graph = new Springy.Graph();
           graph.loadJSON(data);

           $('#graph-canvas').springy({
             graph: graph
           });
        }, 250); // do this in 250 ms may require more time see SO NOTE 2
     }else{
         // throw if nothing can be done. 
         throw new Error("Unable to stop springy.");
     }
     


       
  }else{  // first time so nothing to do but standard start

     graph = new Springy.Graph();
     graph.loadJSON(data);

     $('#graph-canvas').springy({
       graph: graph
     });
   }

}

var graphs = [{
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'e', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['b', 'd', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['c', 'b', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['d', 'a', {color: '#0000ff'}],
    ['c', 'a', {color: '#0000ff'}]
  ]
}, {
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'e', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['b', 'a', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['c', 'e', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['d', 'a', {color: '#00ff00'}],
    ['e', 'b', {color: '#00ff00'}]
  ]
}, {
  nodes: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  edges: [
    ['a', 'd', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['b', 'e', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['c', 'f', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['d', 'f', {color: '#ff0000'}],
    ['e', 'd', {color: '#ff0000'}]
  ]
}]

drawGraph(graphs[2]);

$('#draw-graph').click(function() {
  drawGraph(graphs[Math.floor(Math.random() * graphs.length)])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/springy/2.7.1/springyui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/springy/2.7.1/springy.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph-canvas" width=600 height=600>

</canvas>

<button id="draw-graph">
  change graph
</button>
```

OK that stopped it on my machine and browser (chrome) but It would pay to contact the author of Springy to be safe (if this is public) to find out how to stop it as the documentation and source code does not make it evident at all.